# Difference between int [] and int* as function arguments

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, arguments

This is an interview question:

What is difference between `int []` and `int*`, all of them are input arguments to a function.

```
f(int a[] , int* b)
```

My answers:

For `f()`, they have the same functions. The first one is the beginning position of the first element in `a[]`.

The second one points to an `int`.

But, how to distinguish them from each other without passing other arguments ?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you mean by "distinguish them from eachother".

Comment: I think I understood the question a little differently than Oli - can you clarify a little?

Comment: ¤ As a formal argument the declaration `int a[]` **decays** to `int* b` pointer, and so does e.g. `int a[13]`, it decays to just `int* b` pointer (with the array size discarded). Similarly, as a formal argument the declaration `int foo( double )` decays to `int (*foo)(double)` pointer. Using the pointer syntax directly is a bit more powerful, as it allows `const`/`volatile` qualification of the argument (note: writing `int* const a` instead of just `int* a` does not affect the function signature, since top-level `const` of a formal argument does not affect the signature). Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As function parameters, the two types are exactly the same, `int []` is rewritten to `int *`, and you can't distinguish between them. Many many questions in StackOverflow cover this subject, and the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/) even has a [special section](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) on pointer and arrays (as arguments or not). Take a look into it.

Comment: +1: Correct, though it's worth nothing that this _does not mean that arrays and pointers are the same_

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I decided to add more 4 words just to keep it "clear".

Comment: @sidyll: Better, though strictly speaking it's still not accurate; there is no type `int[]`! This is syntactic sugar, not type equivalence.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Oh man, this drives me crazy. Let it this way, maybe next sunday I can do another edit (not to bump the question unnecessarily?). I may remove the word "type" then. However, while an array type as parameter does not exist after compilation, in the language-side I do believe we can call it this way. Thanks for taking your time to help improving my answer, and sorry if I'm just bothering you with these text corrections.

Comment: @sidyll: But _it's not an array type_. And it's _during_ compilation that this syntactical translation is performed. Like, as an early step, mandated by the language itself. It's not just that the array doesn't exist in the assembly; of course, arrays never exist in the assembly.

Answer (score 6):

In the context of function arguments, they are identical.  All of the following are *exactly* the same:

```
f(int a[], int *b)
f(int a[], int b[])
f(int *a, int *b)
f(int *a, int b[])
```

You cannot distinguish between them without passing some extra information.

Comment: Fair enough :) thanks for the clarification - I think I got muddled up over thinking about passing a statically allocated array into a function.