# How to sort an array by passing to a function as pointer using c?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

Consider an array, which is passed to the function `swap()`, as illustrated in the following quote. I want to implemented a variant of this `swap()` function in order to sort my array.

> These inefficiencies can be removed by an implementation as suggested bu the array concept of the C programming language. The idea is to access array elements through pointers. Another idea is to store addresses that are used multiple times.
>
> ```
> void swap(int *p, int *q) {
>     int t, ai, aj;
>     ai <- *p; aj <- *q;
>     if (ai > aj) {
>         t <- aj;
>         *q <- ai;
>         *p <- t;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Looking more closely at this new code reveals that the temporary variable `t` can be eliminated as well.

I have done it in the following way, but fail to sort the array. Can you check for the error why it does not sort the array?

```
void swap(int array1[], int array2[])
{
    int temp, ai, aj;
    ai = *array1;
    aj = *array2;
    if (ai > aj) /* For decreasing order use < */
    {
        temp = aj;
        aj = ai;
        ai = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[100], n, c, d, swap;

    printf("Enter number of elements\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        scanf("%d", &array[c]);

    for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++)
        {
            swap(array[c], array[d]);
        }
    }

    printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        printf("%d\n", array[c]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does that even compile? I bet the compiler is complaining big time at you

Comment: What compiler warnings do you get? Assuming you have them enabled. But "faster than other methods"? Not unless you inline the function for a simple swap.

Comment: Yeah, it gives error..

Comment: I was not able to call it in the right way: swap(array[c], array[d]); Therefore, the error is here

Comment: @weatherVane. Please check and vote. thanks

Comment: I rollback to the revision 1 because the accepted answer was post and not modified from this revision.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I appreciate.

Comment: @stargateur. How can vote up. I don't like this -2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147218/discussion-between-eid-and-stargateur).

Comment: @Eid I could but you ask me explicitly, This is not good to ask for up vote. Look myself, my question has `-3`, don't worry about down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Sorting only affected local contents.

```
    temp = aj;
    aj = ai;
    ai = temp;
```

Code needs to update values referenced by original pointers.

```
void swap(int array1[], int array2[]){
  int ai = *array1;
  int aj = *array2;
  if (ai > aj) {
    *array1 = aj;
    *array2 = ai;
  }
}
```

2) Code needs to call the `swap()` correctly.  It expect pointers, not `int`.  This implies compiler warnings are not fully enabled.  Be sure to do so - saves you time.

```
// swap(array[c], array[d]);
swap(&array[c], &array[d]);
```

Comment: Yeah, that is true but How can I call it from the main function. Like I have done "swap(array[c], array[d]);", which gives me error

Comment: @Eid - you can't possibly use array reference if you are passing an `int` to the function. You need to at least pass the reference to the function.

Comment: function definition : void swap(int array1[], int array2[]).....
function call: swap(&array[c],&array[d]);.....Gives the same error

Comment: function definition is still wrong:

void swap(int* val1, int* val2)

feel free to check the edit to my answer

Comment: @user3164339 You are mistaken if you think `void swap(int array1[], int array2[])` differs in functionality from `void swap(int *array1, int *array2)`.  There are the same.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424716/difference-between-int-and-int-as-function-arguments

Comment: @Eid "Gives the same error" --> What exactly is that error?

Comment: @Eid I can only up vote a question once.  Recommend you do not ask for votes as that atrtacks down votes from others.

Answer (score 1):

ok , you have declared swap as

```
void swap(int array1[], int array2[])
```

but you call it with

```
swap(array[c], array[d]);
```

so the declaration says it takes two int arrays as params but you pass it two ints.

If you want swap (btw it should be called swap_if_needed) to excahnge 2 elements of the arrays then it needs to be declared as

```
void swap(int array, int idx1, int idx2);
```

and called by

```
swap(array,c,d);
```

I leave it to you to correct the body of swap

If you want to do it like the book then you need to declare swal as

```
void swap(int *x, int * y);
```

and call it like this

```
swap(&array[c], &array[d]);
```

Comment: You are right, but the execution time will not be effected the way you have done. I want to access array elements using pointers

Comment: Perhaps `void swap(int *array, int idx1, int idx2);`?  (need *)

Comment: calling function: swap(array, c, d);
....and the function definition....void swap(int *ar, int c, int d)...Still does not work

Comment: you need to repost your code to show what you have now, and say whats 'not working'